# R missing bib key in citation() output

Tags: r

I am using citation() to automatically get the bib entries for R packages. However, its output does not have a key.

Example:

```
utils:::print.bibentry(citation(), style = "Bibtex")
```

Output:

```
@Manual{,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2017},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
@Manual{mykey999,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2017},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
}
```

I've tried the same command with the "key" argument but it changes nothing:

```
utils:::print.bibentry(citation(), style = "Bibtex", key= "mykey0")
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
z = citation()
z$key = "Hullo"
print(z, "Bibtex")
```

which gives

```
@Manual{Hullo,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2017},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
}
```

Alternately, there's the silly one-liner:

```
print(`$<-`(citation(), key, "Hullo"), "Bibtex")
```

---

I guess using `:::` to access `print` (as in the OP) is overkill here. If you like looking at internals, though, maybe have a gander at `` utils:::`$<-.bibentry` ``. From there, you can see that expected assignments are to...

```
utils:::bibentry_attribute_names
# [1] "bibtype"     "textVersion" "header"      "footer"      "key"
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime an R user applies the function, they will get the same result by definition of the function itself. You have to copy the output result (bib entry) or write it to a file and there you can choose and the bibkey to any bibkey you want.